# Запрос к таблице

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, таблицы

Как можно сделать вот такой запрос к таблице: "/response.php?que=есть"? У меня работает только с цифрами

$query = "SELECT ans FROM `capbase` WHERE QUE=".$_GET['que'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки нужно обернуть в кавычки

```
$query = "SELECT ans FROM capbase WHERE QUE = '" . $_GET['que'] . "'";
```